# Create a probability map of image with Kernel Density Estimation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kernel-density

I'm working with mammograms that have calcifications (which are brighter spots than the surrounding tissue).

This is one of the images I have:
[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAd92.png)

I got this image by creating a heat map:
[heat map of original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZAPN.png)

But the heat map considers the overall brightness of the image. To create a probability map that considers the local luminosity I have thought about making a Kernel Density Estimation with a Gaussian filter, but I am having problems with the implementation.

My aim is to get a result similar to scikit-learn's "Kernel Density Estimate of Species Distributions" example. This is the code I tried to use:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

img = cv.imread("mammo.tif", 0)

kde = KernelDensity(kernel="gaussian")
kde.fit(img)

sco = kde.score_samples(img)
```

The original image has a size of 4084x3328. I would like to get a probability map of the same size, but what I get in the variable `sco` is a vector of 4084x1 with all negative values.

Answer (score 0):

In `kde.fit(img)` every row of `img` is treated as a single observation with 3328 features. Thus you are fitting a kernel density estimate where the kernel is a multivariate Gaussian distribution with 3328 variables. Then `kde.score_samples(img)` again computes the score for each row of `img` which results in 4084 values. Moreover, these values are logarithms of probabilities - hence they are negative.

Comment: Ok clear, so before doing `kde.fit(img)` I should do a reshape of `img` to have a vector instead of a matrix?

Comment: @Nicola You can reshape the image into an array with 4084x3328 rows and one column (`kde.fit()` expects a 2-dimensional array), use it to fit KDE, and then compute scores. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but this probably will not be helpful.  The result will reflect the overall distribution of brightness levels in the whole image and not the local structure of the image.